# Why correlation matrix's column is smaller than pandas Dataframe's

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

When I use `pandas.DataFrame.corr()` to create a correlation matrix, I found the correlation matrix(`corr_matrix`) has 37 columns and the DataFrame(`all_data`) has 80 columns. In my mind, these two columns should be the same. In another word, the correlation matrix should have the shape (80 x 80). But this did not happen. I have imputed all missing data before creating the correlation matrix. So why the two columns are not equal?

**The code**

```
corr_matrix = all_data.corr(method="kendall").abs()
print("Missing value descending:\n{}\n".format(all_data.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)[:5]))
print("Original Dataframe shape: {}".format(all_data.shape))
print("Correlation Matrix shape: {}".format(corr_matrix.shape))
```

**The output**

Missing value descending:

MSSubClass     0

MSZoning       0

GarageYrBlt    0

GarageType     0

FireplaceQu    0

dtype: int64

Original Dataframe shape: (2904, 80)

Correlation Matrix shape: (37, 37)

Comment: Do you have perhaps have columns with the same name?

Comment: @CeliusStingher Thank you very much. But none of the columns have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `train` DataFrame contain categorical columns?

Only the correlation between numerical columns is considered, categorical columns are ignored. At least, based on the following example

```
train = pd.DataFrame({
    "cat1": list("ABC"),
    "cat2": list("xyz"),
    "num1": [1,2,3],
    "num2": [-2,10,-5]
})

# 2 numerical and 2 categorical columns
>>> train 

  cat1 cat2  num1  num2
0    A    x     1    -2
1    B    y     2    10
2    C    z     3    -5

# only numerical columns are present 
>>> train.corr(method="kendall").abs()

          num1      num2
num1  1.000000  0.333333
num2  0.333333  1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is helpful. The reason is categorical features. After I encoded my categorical features, the correlation matrix's shape became (80 x 80).